# I'm using selenium undetected-chromedriver and I can't open multiple profiles at once and navigate through them

Tags: python, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

it only works for first profile and for others it just creates and open them with no actions. here is my code

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

open_from = 14
open_to = 16
chrome_debugger_base_port = 9000


for i in range(open_from, open_to + 1):
# create a new Chrome profile
    chrome_options = Options()
   
    chrome_options.binary_location = "C:\\Users...\\Chrome-bin\\chrome.exe"
    chrome_options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\..\\Profiles\\GoogleChromePortable\\Data")
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"--profile-directory=Profile {i}")
    

    # specify a different port number for each instance of Chrome
    chrome_debugger_port = chrome_debugger_base_port + i
    print(chrome_debugger_port)
    chrome_options.debugger_address = f"127.0.0.1:{chrome_debugger_port}"
   
   
    try:
        # start the Chrome browser with the new profile
        # time.sleep(5)

        driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        time.sleep(2)

        driver.get("chrome://version/")
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/")

        driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

I tried to add a debugger_address and iterate throught dofferent ports but it gives me this error:
An error occurred: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9015
from chrome not reachable

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\anyPathWhereYouWantToSaveYourUserData\\profile1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Windows\System32\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
```